# on page load event of *not the focus* tab in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, events, firefox-addon

I develop firefox extension and using the "load" and "DOMContentLoaded" events to raise when document was fully loaded.

My problem, however, is that my 'content' variable is always pointing to the focused tab and not to the new loaded tab (for example, when firefox restarts and load several tabs or if you right-click a link and open it in new tab <-- then it load in the background and does not change the currently visible tab)

How can I get the 'content' variable of the newly created page?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just to clarify on this: I can get the HTML document (similar to content.document) by reading "aEvent.originalTarget" (when aEvent is the param for my DOMContentLoaded event function), but what I need is the 'content' variable itself...

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Not really... I had to save the loaded tabs and upon changing focus I check if I'm on one of the "unhandled tabs", run my code and remove it from the list. It's working pretty well actually but only if you can wait until you get the focus on the tab rather than running your code immediately